# Why does Firefox rotate an element differently than Chrome/Safari?

Tags: css, cross-browser

In the jsFiddle below why does Firefox rotate the container differently than Chrome or Safari?

http://jsfiddle.net/CRc9d/

**Browser Version Info:**

- Firefox 7.0.1
- Safari 5.1.1
- Chrome 15.0.874.120

In Chrome and Safari the container rotates gradually whereas in Firefox the container rotates immediately.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue. Could you give us the browser versions?

Comment: Just updated, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps... I replaced

```
-moz-transition-property: rotate;
-moz-transition-duration: .17s;
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
```

with

```
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.17s linear;
```

And it works fine. Could be a syntax thing... I'm taking a look at the mozilla developer network to confirm.

Here's the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRc9d/10/).

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I'm going to take a shot and see if you can help with an anti-aliasing problem I'm having in Safari with this transition. Here's the question if you have a moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947385/hovering-over-css-transition-in-safari-lightens-certain-font-color/8074310#8074310